# Panning QScrollArea with a mouse

Tags: qt

I have a `QScrollArea`. I would like to make the context pannable with a mouse - such that, a hand cursor is shown over the area and click-and-hold gets us into dragging mode.

This would be similar to what QGraphicsView can do easily with `QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag` dragging mode, only that I need it for `QScrollArea`.

Any idea on how to have it out of the box? Or perhaps a piece of code to do it manually? I am certainly not the first one who wants it..

Comment: QScrollArea just has a viewport widget inside it. It can be any QWidget based class. You could create one that handles mouse down, move and release events and inform the scroll area where to scroll to as a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not be difficult, especially using event filter. Take a look at my old blog post on [Flick list or kinetic scrolling](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2008/11/15/flick-list-or-kinetic-scrolling/) (the code has been moved to http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/graphics-dojo). As a bonus, you can get the momentum effect easily!

Comment: The links are dead now, are there any alternative sources?

Comment: There is also a live link to a Python version of his code: http://code.google.com/p/flickcharm-python/   (archived link: https://web.archive.org/web/20140809022603/http://code.google.com/p/flickcharm-python/)

Comment: A live link to the "Flick list or kinetic scrolling" blog post: https://www.qt.io/blog/2008/11/15/flick-list-or-kinetic-scrolling  (archived link: https://archive.ph/OUqfT)

Answer (score 0):

Okay. At the end I changed it to QGraphicsView and it was easy to do, worked great out of the box.